# React Child component not sent the updated state from parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

I am trying to follow the react tutorial on their official site: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

Only difference is I am trying to implement it by only using functional components, here is my code on code pen:

**See the Pen 
  [React tutorial functional component](https://codepen.io/snedden-gonsalves/pen/RwPaWRQ) by Snedden Gonsalves ([@snedden-gonsalves](https://codepen.io/snedden-gonsalves))
  on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).**

To summarize; I have simple square component that draws individual squares, a parent board component that draws a 3x3 square board and an overarching game component that maintains state ,like history, current square, current turn etc as in the tutorial.
I currently send the squares from the parent game-component to board components like so :

```
<Board
   onClick ={(i)=>{handleClick(i)}}
   squares = {state.history[state.history.length - 1]}
```

/>

The handleClick creates new squares state and appends it to the history array which I assume should be dynamically passed as I also pass the last entry in the array , but it doesn't look it passes the last entry at all to the child components. Not sure what is happening..

Thanks for you time.

**Components:**

Square:

```
 const Square = (props)=>{
        return(
            <button className="square" onClick={(e)=>props.onClick()}>
                {props.value}
            </button>
        )
    }
```

Board:

```
const Board = (props) => {
    const renderSquare = (i)=>{
        return <Square
            value={props.squares[i]}
            onClick={() => {
                props.onClick(i)
                }
            }
        />
    }
    return(
        <div>
            <div className="board-row">
                {renderSquare(0)}
                {renderSquare(1)}
                {renderSquare(2)}
            </div>
            <div className="board-row">
                {renderSquare(3)}
                {renderSquare(4)}
                {renderSquare(5)}
            </div>
            <div className="board-row">
                {renderSquare(6)}
                {renderSquare(7)}
                {renderSquare(8)}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Game:

```
const Game = () =>{
    let [state, setState] = useState({
        history:[{
            squares:Array(9).fill(null)
        }],
        isXNext:true,
        status:'Next player X'
    });

    useEffect(() =>{
        const currentSquares = state.history[state.history.length - 1].squares;
        const winner = calculateWinner(currentSquares);
        if(winner){
            setState( state => ({...state, status:'Winner is ' + winner, ended:true}));
        }
    },[state.history]);


    const handleClick = (i) =>{
        const currentSquares = state.history[state.history.length - 1].squares;

        if(state.ended || currentSquares[i])
            return;

        const newSquares = currentSquares.slice();
        newSquares[i] = state.isXNext?'X':'O';

        const newIsXNext = !state.isXNext;
        const newHistory = state.history.concat([
            {squares:newSquares}]);

        setState(state => ({...state,
            history: newHistory,
            isXNext: newIsXNext,
            status:'Next player ' + (newIsXNext?'X':'O')
        }));

    }

    return(
        <div className="game">
            <div className="game-board">
                <Board
                    onClick ={(i)=>{handleClick(i)}}
                    squares = {state.history[state.history.length - 1]}
                />
            </div>
            <div className="game-info">
                <div>{state.status}</div>
                <ol>{/* TODO */}</ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So turns out it was passing  the updated state I was not using the right key, this is how I fixed it:

```
<Board
    onClick ={(i)=>{handleClick(i)}}
    squares = {state.history[state.history.length - 1].squares}/>
```

Working code pen:

See the Pen 
  [React tutorial functional component Working](https://codepen.io/snedden-gonsalves/pen/OJVNyKK) by Snedden Gonsalves ([@snedden-gonsalves](https://codepen.io/snedden-gonsalves))
  on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).